# Calculate number of sentences

Tags: java, arrays

I have a simple loop that calculating the input sentences. It works good when punctuation mark repeat once, but they can be combined like "!!!" or "???". So, it's calculating it like different sentences and i should check the next char if it's not a mark. I don't have any ideas, thank you for your time!

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.println("Please enter your sentence");
String line =br.readLine();
String delimiters = "?!.";
int count=0;

for(int i=0;i<line.length();i++) {

    if (delimiters.indexOf(line.charAt(i))!=-1) {
        count++;
    }
}
System.out.println("There are "+count+" sentences");
```

Comment: Have you already covered regular expressions?

Comment: It might be easier to use a regular expression

Comment: If you know about regular expressions, you could use the `split` method, and an expression that matches any number of those punctuation characters.  If you don't know about regular expressions, you could put an additional loop inside your `if` statement to advance `i` to the last punctuation character in the group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skip repeating characters, i.e. only check if it is a delimiter if the character is different from previous character.

```
String delimiters = "?!.";
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
    if (i == 0 || line.charAt(i) != line.charAt(i - 1)) {
        if (delimiters.indexOf(line.charAt(i)) != -1) {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

---

As some has suggested in comments, you can also use regex, e.g. like this:

```
int count = line.replaceAll("([?!.])+|[^?!.]+", "$1").length();
```

This regex solution only counts adjacent delimiter characters once, even if they are different, e.g. if `line = "This is a text. No a test!! Why?!?!?"`, then you get `count = 3`.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I know, I already said that in the answer. The first part is to simply fix what OP asked for. The second part is show alternative single-line regex solution, that also fixes the mixed-delimiter issue.